# HTML 5- How to get around a validation error?- Element div not allowed as child of element h1 in this context

Tags: css, html, validation

I need to assign divs to style them with jQuery, as this is the task of my assignment. It is showing just fine, but does not pass validation.

The error is element div not allowed as child of element h1 in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

```
 <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div id="slogan">
                <h1 class="brand-heading">Love Life Strong <div id="decorate">Powerful</div> Give</h1>
            </div>



$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slogan").hover(function(){
  $("#slogan").css({
    backgroundColor: '#ff1d8e'
    });//end css
  $("#decorate").css("text-decoration","underline");
  },function(){
  $("#slogan").css({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    });//end css
  $("#decorate").css("text-decoration","none");
});//end slogan decoration
```

CSS:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.heading .heading-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Is there another way to use the hover function in jQuery without this HTML error?

Bonus question:
Is there an easy way to change this screeming pink color to a pink text shadow in the jQuery? (Id do it with CSS, but maybe there is an easy way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `div` in `h#` tag. You can use `span` instead. You can make `span` act like `div` using `display: inline-block;`/`display: block;`

```
<h1 class="brand-heading">
    Love Life Strong <span id="decorate">Powerful</span> Give
</h1>
```

Bonus answer:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=135, Color=#ff1d8e)";/*IE 8*/
text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ff1d8e;/* FF3.5+, Opera 9+, Saf1+, Chrome, IE10 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=135, Color=#ff1d8e); /*IE 5.5-7*/
```

Either add it via jQuery or css (css is better).

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider this?

```
<h1 class="brand-heading">Love Life Strong <span id="decorate">Powerful</span> Give</h1>
```

For hovering, you can simply add a css rule:

```
#slogan:hover {
    background-color: #ff1d8e;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use span tags to style the element nested within the h1 header.

Like this: `<h1 class="brand-heading">Love Life Strong <span id="decorate">Powerful</span> Give</h1>`

You can set the css text-shadow property the same way you're setting your other styles with jquery in your code sample. It has a color option.